# How to create surface mesh from a given 2D mesh toplogy?

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I would like  to convert a very easy(examplary) mesh(2D)

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> -{{0, 0}, {1, -.5}, {0.7, .8}, {0, 1}},
"MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 4}}]}, 
"BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4,1}}]},
"PointElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, \{4}}]}]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

by changing the Coordinates(2D-3D) and assuming the 3Dmesh to be a boundary mesh:

```
ToBoundaryMesh[
"Coordinates" ->Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], RandomReal[]} &, {{0,0}, {1, -.5}, {0.7, .8}, {0, 1}}],
"MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 4}}]}, 
"BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4,1}}]} 
]["Wireframe"]
```

MMA evaluates the expression without error bur doesn't show the mesh!

What's going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: For 3D `ToBoundaryMesh[rules]` syntax you should pass surface elements to `"BoundaryElements"` rule and set `"MeshElements"->Automatic`.

Comment: @Pinti Thank you, `ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> 
   Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], RandomReal[]} &, {{0, 
      0}, {1, -.5}, {0.7, .8}, {0, 1}}], 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 
       4}}]}]["Wireframe"]` works without MeshElement!

Answer (score 4):

To not leave this unanswered:

```
ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> 
   Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], RandomReal[]} &, {{0, 
      0}, {1, -.5}, {0.7, .8}, {0, 1}}], 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 4}}]}][
 "Wireframe"[Boxed -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: @ user21  Thank you!